# thymeleaf template not getting all response while sending request in chrome, I am receiving data from database is there any error in binding?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

**Flight**

```
package com.shahbaz.flightreservation.entities;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
@Entity
public class Flight extends AbstractEntity {

    private String flightNumber;
    private String operatingAirlines;
    private String departureCity;
    private String arrivalCity;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateOfDeparture;
    private Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime;
    
    public String getFlightNumber() {
        return flightNumber;
    }
    public void setFlightNumber(String flightNumber) {
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
    }
    public String getOperatingAirlines() {
        return operatingAirlines;
    }
    public void setOperatingAirlines(String operatingAirlines) {
        this.operatingAirlines = operatingAirlines;
    }
    public String getDepartureCity() {
        return departureCity;
    }
    public void setDepartureCity(String departureCity) {
        this.departureCity = departureCity;
    }
    public String getArrivalCity() {
        return arrivalCity;
    }
    public void setArrivalCity(String arrivalCity) {
        this.arrivalCity = arrivalCity;
    }
    public Date getDateOfDeparture() {
        return dateOfDeparture;
    }
    public void setDateOfDeparture(Date dateOfDeparture) {
        this.dateOfDeparture = dateOfDeparture;
    }
    public Timestamp getEstimatedDepartureTime() {
        return estimatedDepartureTime;
    }
    public void setEstimatedDepartureTime(Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime) {
        this.estimatedDepartureTime = estimatedDepartureTime;
    }
    
}
```

**AbstractEntity**

package com.shahbaz.flightreservation.entities;

```
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

****FlightRepository****

```
package com.shahbaz.flightreservation.repos;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.shahbaz.flightreservation.entities.Flight;
@Repository
public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight,Long> {
    
    @Query("from Flight where departureCity=:departureCity and arrivalCity=:arrivalCity and dateOfDeparture=:dateOfDeparture")
    List<Flight> findFlights(@Param("departureCity") String from, @Param("arrivalCity") String to,
            @Param("dateOfDeparture")  Date departureDate);
    @Query("from Flight where id=:id")
    Flight findOne(@Param("id") Long flightId);
    
    
}
```

**ReservationController**

```
package com.shahbaz.flightreservation.controllers;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.shahbaz.flightreservation.entities.Flight;
import com.shahbaz.flightreservation.repos.FlightRepository;

@Controller
public class ReservationController {

    @Autowired
    FlightRepository flightRepository;
    
    @RequestMapping("/showCompleteReservation")
    public String showCompleteReservation(@RequestParam("flightId") Long flightId,ModelMap modelMap)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome Home");
        Flight flight = flightRepository.findOne(flightId);
        modelMap.addAttribute("flights", flight);
        System.out.println(flight.getArrivalCity());
        System.out.println(flight.getDepartureCity());
        return "completeReservation";
    }
    
}
```

**completeReservation**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Complete Reservation</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Complete Reservation</h2>
Airline: <span th:text="${flight.operatingAirlines}"> <br/>
Departure City:  <span th:text="${flight.departureCity}"><br/>
Arrival City:<spanp th:text="${flight.arrivalCity}"><br/>

<form action="completeReservation" method="post">
<pre>
<h2>Passenger Details:</h2>
First Name:<input type="text" name="passengerFirstName"/>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="passengerLastName"/>
Email:<input type="text" name="passengerEmail"/>
Phone:<input type="text" name="passengerPhone"/>

<h2>Card Details:</h2>
Name on the card:<input type="text" name="nameOnTheCard"/>
Card No:<input type="text" name="cardNumber"/>
Expiry Date:<input type="text" name="expirationDate"/>
Three Digit Sec Code:<input type="text" name="securityCode"/>

<input type="hidden" name="flightId" th:value="${flight.id}"/>
<input type="submit" value="confirm"/>
</pre>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**While Debugging the code I am Getting Values from database But i am not getting all values while sending request in chrome.I am Getting only Airline value.If anyone can help me to find out the error I tried but unable to come up with solution as i am new to thymeleaf**

Answer (score 1):

You are adding your `flight` instance under the `flights` key to the model while in the Thymeleaf template, you use `${flight....}`.

Changing this:

```
modelMap.addAttribute("flights", flight);
```

to

```
modelMap.addAttribute("flight", flight);
```

should help.